# ASP.NET CORE app is showing index.html page on startup page although I do not have any middle ware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am learning asp.net core. I have used `UseStaticFiles()` and `UseDefaultFiles()` middleware and added `wwwroot` folder and `index.html` file in that folder but now when I have removed all my middleware application is still showing the same index.html page

Here is my `Configure` method from `Startup` class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)  //logger is needed to log
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //DeveloperExceptionPageOptions options = new DeveloperExceptionPageOptions() { SourceCodeLineCount = 10 };
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() ;
            }

            //app.Use(async (context,nextMiddleware) =>  // we need to call next middleware so we need to register it this way
            //{
            //    logger.LogInformation("First Request");
            //    await nextMiddleware();
            //    logger.LogInformation("First Response");
            //});

            //to use default files
            //DefaultFilesOptions defaultFilesOptions = new DefaultFilesOptions();
            //defaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
            //defaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("Home.html");
            //app.UseDefaultFiles(defaultFilesOptions);

            //to use static pages 
            //app.UseStaticFiles();

            // file server
            //FileServerOptions fileServerOptions = new FileServerOptions();
            //fileServerOptions.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
            //fileServerOptions.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames.Add("Home.html");
            //app.UseFileServer(fileServerOptions);

            //app.UseFileServer();  //this combines the finctionality of use defaulfiles and usestat



            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                //throw new Exception("some error processing");
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Env Variable "+env.EnvironmentName);

            });
        }
```

I tried below thing:

I removed index.html from my IIS->Default website section. Read some answers but did not help

Comment: `Clean` your solution and `Rebuild` . Secondly go to properties of the solution and check the `startup link` that you have set.

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadAftab Sir. It resolved it.